# How clone image in pure js

Tags: javascript, html, image, copy, clone

I wrote JS to clone image and attached this action to button.
It works but I'm not sure that this better way to do it.

My questions:

- is it correct to use querySelector to return elements, or is it better to add additional classes or id for buttons and pictures?
- use cloneNode is optimal or better use other ways in this case?

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  document.querySelector('button[action="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let image = document.querySelector('img[alt="Dog"]');
    let cln = image.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('image-section').appendChild(cln);
  });
})();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="overview">
     <section class="section--center">
       <button action="button">Yeah, I want more dogs!</button>
     </section>
     <section class="section--center" id='image-section'>
        <img src="https://www.purina.com/sites/g/files/auxxlc196/files/styles/kraken_generic_max_width_480/public/HOUND_Beagle-%2813inch%29.jpg?itok=lN915WHC" alt="Dog" style="width: 150px">
     </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: query selectors are not exclusive with usage of classes and ids, and I would definitively recomment adding classes and ids. Querying by action, and especially a generic one like "button" just seems foreign.

Comment: querying by id will be a lot faster than a query selector - querying by attribute is one of the slowest queries.  You probably want to post this in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you are just wanting it optimised

Answer (score 0):

Another option is updating innerHTML, but it's not better.
An approach should solve a task, so it depends on the task.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  document.querySelector('button[action="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('image-section').innerHTML +=
    document.querySelector('img[alt="Dog"]').outerHTML;
  });
})();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="overview">
     <section class="section--center">
       <button action="button">Yeah, I want more dogs!</button>
     </section>
     <section class="section--center" id='image-section'>
        <img src="https://www.purina.com/sites/g/files/auxxlc196/files/styles/kraken_generic_max_width_480/public/HOUND_Beagle-%2813inch%29.jpg?itok=lN915WHC" alt="Dog" style="width: 150px">
     </section>
  </div>
</body>
```